# compare between two tagged objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, if-statement

I have 2 buttons, each one with tag. how can I compare between them, each with his own tag and image. for example:

```
// sender is (UIButton *)sender.

if ((sender.tag == 1)theImageOnTheButton == (sender.tag == 2)theImageOnTheButton
{
    // egual
}
else
    // not egual
```

so, if the sender than tagged as 1, his image is equal to the sender with tag 2, his image are equal, say equal, else, say that they are not egual. how can I do that?

the original code is:

```
-(void)flipView:(UIButton*)sender
{    
    x = x + 1;
    if (x == 1)
    {
        //  When flipping the first card
        NSLog(@"X == 1");
        [sender setTag:1];
    }
    else if (x == 2)
    {
        //  When flipping the second card
        NSLog(@"X == 2");
        x = 0;
        [sender setTag:2];

        if ((sender.tag == 2) == (sender.tag == 1))
        {
            NSLog(@"IGUAL");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"NOT EGUAL");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks allot.

Comment: I think you will need to rephrase your question because it currently makes no sense. The code you posted is a readable/valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If I have more than two buttons then how can i compare the images?

suppose you have two buttons with tags

```
IBOutlet UIButton *btn1, *btn2;

btn1.tag = 1;
btn2.tag = 2;
```

connect these two IBOutlet buttons to your buttons in your xid file and for both add a common IBAction.

```
 -(IBAction)checkingBtns:(id)sender
  {

  if([sender tag] == 1){
      //Do what ever with your btn1 change color, change text, change image
    }

   if([sender tag] == 2){
      //Do what ever with your btn2 change color, change text, change image
    }

   }
```

hope this will help you !! properly connect the oulets and actions for proper function

Answer (score 0):

```
[sender setTag:2];
```

and then -

```
if ((sender.tag == 2) == (sender.tag == 1))
```

when already tag is set to 2, then how can it be equal to 1? Wrong logic.